# Post XML data to Zoho CRM from android

Tags: java, android, xml, zoho

I am trying to do a posturl to Zoho CRM from my android application and I cannot figure out the proper formatting. Here is how the URL layout is supposed to be (in this EXACT format):

`https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Potentials/updateRecords?authtoken=myauthtoken&scope=crmapi&id=potentialsid&xmlData=<Potentials><row no="1"><FL val="field name goes here">field value goes here</FL>(repeat <FL val="field name goes here">field value goes here</FL> for every field you want populated)</row></Potentials>`.

I have tried this as just a straight url in a web browser and it worked in updating the field that I wanted updated with this format, so I know this is the proper format, but I just don't know how to replicate this in android.

If it helps, the same number of fields will need to be updated every time, so I will need a set number of `<FL val="field name goes here">field value goes here</FL>` values, in my case, 5 of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I actually figured out a sort of workaround for how to post data to Zoho CRM from Android. First, I am using [HttpAgent](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3756) to Post the URL. Next, in the HttpAgent.post(), I have the following layout for my URL:

```
    HttpAgent.post("https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Potentials/
updateRecords?authtoken=myauthtoken&scope=crmapi&id=potentialsid&xmlData=
<Potentials><row no="1">" + data + "</row></Potentials>)
```

The data variable is a series of StringBuffers with the following layout:

```
StringBuffer variablename1 = new StringBuffer();
                        if(Checkboxname1.isChecked()){
                            variablename.append("<FL%20val=\"CRM Field Name\">CRM Field Value</FL>");
                        }
```

I need the if statement to check to see if a certain checkbox is checked and if it is, to update the CRM field the checkbox is associated with in my case, others may not need it. I then append them together with the following code:

```
StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();

data.append(variablename1.toString() + variablename2.toString()...);
```

The data variable is then just plugged into the url where "data" has been concatenated. You then just finish it off with a simple

```
.go(new SuccessCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    protected void onDone(boolean success) {

                                    }
                                });
```

and you are good to go. Make sure to add %20 between ALL spaces that will be going into the URL. I didn't know that at first and it wasn't posting.

This is my total code for all who are wondering:

```
StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();

                        StringBuffer variable1 = new StringBuffer();
                        if(checkboxname1.isChecked()){
                            variable1.append("<FL%20val=\"CRM%20Field%20Name%201\">CRM%20Field%20Value%201</FL>"); //Make sure to add %20 between ALL spaces, that threw me off for awhile.
                        }
                        StringBuffer variable2= new StringBuffer();
                        if(checkboxname2.isChecked()){
                            variable2.append("<FL%20val=\"CRM%20Field%20Name%202\">CRM%20Field%20Value%202</FL>");
                        }

                        data.append(variable1.toString() + variable2.toString());



                        HttpAgent.post("https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Potentials/updateRecords?authtoken=myauthtoken&scope=crmapi&id=" + PotentialID + "&xmlData=<Potentials><row%20no=\"1\">" + data + "</row></Potentials>")


                                .go(new SuccessCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    protected void onDone(boolean success) {

                                    }
                                });
```

P.S. I will be adding all 5 that I need in a little while, I just wanted to post the code so anyone looking for an easy answer can find it.